# Magento Catalog Export into CSV / PDF Template

Tags: xml, excel, magento

Curious to see if it has been done or is possible.  Every week I have to export my products into an excel csv or xls file with 3 specific columns - sku, name, price.  I have a macro Excel file setup to take this data, organize it based upon sku into categories and make it pretty in a nicely made template.

Possible to Export or Automate a script to take current stock, and push it into a premade price list format downloadable by customers in an .xls / .pdf format?

Would be awesome If I can implement that into my newsletter template with links to each instead of all this manual fussing about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite possible. Magento inherently support exporting to csv and excel. Magento advanced profile allows to do the data format much the way you want, but your case you may have write custom module to override the current export functionality, then you may have to wire a cron job to export the data with desired predefined time intervals. Hope this helps.